# YII logging for debugging

Tags: php, cakephp, yii

In many cases, `Xdebug` is not suitable for debugging as it involves clicks to run to a particular line of codes. I want to use something that is similar to `cakePHP` debug function for developers to output the value of a particular property of a class to the browser.

I am using `Yii framework` and this is my configuration for the `yii log` in the `main.php`:

```
'log'=>array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'trace, info, error, warning, vardump',
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                                'enabled' => YII_DEBUG,
            'levels'=>'error, warning, trace, log, vardump',
            'showInFireBug'=>true,
        ),
    ),
),
```

In one of my defined controller i put this code to test:

```
Yii::log("CallFromUserController",'info', 'application');
```

However i don't see this being printed in the firebug. I used Chris's example:

> http://chris-backhouse.com/advanced-logging-in-yii/775

Comment: You don't have the 'info'  level (which is what you specify as the second argument to Yii::log())  enabled for CWebLogRoute so of course what you try won't work.

Comment: Ok, i tried it too but it didn't work. The below solution worked for me though :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally managed to find out a solution:

In my main.php I did this:

```
'log' => array(
    'class' => 'CLogRouter',
    'routes' => array(
        array(
            'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
            'levels' => 'trace, info, error, warning, vardump',
        ),
        // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
        array(
            'class' => 'CWebLogRoute',
            'enabled' => YII_DEBUG,
            'levels' => 'error, warning, trace, notice',
            'categories' => 'application',
            'showInFireBug' => false,
        ),
    ),
),
```

In my controller I used this code:

```
$a = new array(1,2,3);
Yii::trace(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($a));
```

The Application Log is shown below in every page.

Answer (score 1):

## In Yii2

```
Yii::trace(VarDumper::dumpAsString($array));
```

An example of customized log class is given below.

```
<?php

namespace app\helpers;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\VarDumper;

class Log {

    const LOG_CATEGORY_NAME = 'myLog';

    public static function e($msg, $data) {

        if (isset($data)) {
            $msg .= " " . VarDumper::dumpAsString($data);
        }   
        Yii::error($msg, self::LOG_CATEGORY_NAME);
    }   
}
```

Example:

```
 Log.e("Copying the Estimate data failed. Model::getError(): ", 
        $model->getErrors());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add following lines to your protected/main.php file for debug:true mode. Trust work like a charm !

```
return array(
    'preload' => array(
        'debug',
    ),
    'components' => array(
        'debug' => array(
            'class' => 'ext.yii2-debug.Yii2Debug',


         ),
            'db' => array(
                'enableProfiling' => true,
                'enableParamLogging' => true,
            ),
        ),
    );
```